# likelihood of Gamma distribution confusion

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood

Gamma is given by $$f_X{(x)} = \frac{\lambda^a x^{a-1}e^{-\lambda x}}{\Gamma(a)}$$

I can remove the constant being $\frac{x^{a-1}}{\Gamma(a)}$

$$L(\theta | x_{1}, x_2, \cdots, x_n = \bar{x}) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} \theta^a e^{-\theta x_i} = \theta^{an} e^{- \sum_{i=1}^{n} \theta x_i} = \theta^{an} e^{- \theta^n\bar{x}n}$$

since $\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i = n\bar{x}$

the answer to this is $$\theta^{an} e^{- \theta \bar{x}n}$$

without the $\theta^n$. So where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
...=\theta^{an} e^{- \sum_{i=1}^{n} \theta x_i} 
=\theta^{an} e^{- \theta n \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i}
 = \theta^{an} e^{- \theta\bar{x}n}
$$